How to create Kusto function for getting delta records in azure data explorer
I created a ADF pipeline for copying data from Azure data explorer Kusto to dataverse, using query option, in source having 200k records, but I need to copy delta load, how can I write function in kusto
I'm trying to create a ADF pipeline for copying data from Kusto to dataverse using copy activity with query option, i need delta load copy to dataverse. How can I create Kusto function for delta records

please when possible paste your code here. Avoid sharing code in pics. Makes it easier to read and reproduce your issue :)

I written Kusto query function like this..(. create -or-alter function _dynamics_getSubsidiarySummary(){cluster ('cceadxcmcusppe1.centralus'). database('customerSubscriptionstore').get latest subsidiaries | join kind=inner (CustomerSummary | project accountnumber, accountid) on $left.parentCustomerID==$right.accountnumber | project SubsidiaryID, Subsidiaryname, accountid | project -rename parentaccountid = accountid | extend parent_entity_reference = 'account'}

In order to copy only the delta records from Kusto, you can use query option in the copy activity.

Give the query in the query text box of copy activity.



Query should be written in such a way that it filters only the required delta records from the source.

For example, if your data looks like,
date, id
2024-01-01,1
2024-02-01,2
2024-03-02,3

If you have copied all above records and then if delta records are like below,
date, id
2024-04-01,4
2024-05-04,5

You can give the query in copy activity like,
table1
|where date>'2024-03-02'

This way you can copy the delta records from kusto.

I'm using query option in that writing Kusto function..like this way(_dynamics_getSubsidiarySummary | take 500)

It is failed error: Async reparent db is currently executing for this entity.

What is the function are you writing?

_dynamics_getSubsidiarySummary | take 500

_dynamics_getSubsidiarySummary what function is this?

Kusto query function

Please share screenshot for better understanding

Why don't you write table name instead of function name?

I'm new to writing Kusto queries, if I'm write table name is it working? And how can I write in that function, give any ideas

Yes, it works for table for me

How can i write query function?

I added screenshot for writing query function, how to write query function in ADF

Can you run the same query in ADX successfully?

Yes, running successfully, but my question is how to write query in ADF query table
